# AngularJS Router app freezes webpage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

First, I was able to fix the blank page by updating the CDN links. It was able to load the header.html and footer.html without any error messages, but it freezes when trying to display a view page. I'm not sure if it has to do with the `app.js` or the CDN `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js` link?

No JS console errors.

app.js

```
var myApp= angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'index.html'
})
    .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'views/about.html'
})
    .when('/contact', {
    templateUrl: 'views/contact.html'
})
    .when('/business', {
    templateUrl: 'views/business-interpreting.html'
})
    .when('/deafconsumers', {
    templateUrl: 'views/deaf-consumers.html'
})
    .when('/educational', {
    templateUrl: 'views/educational-interpreting.html'
})
    .when('/recruitment', {
    templateUrl: 'views/interpreter-recruitment.html'
})
    .when('/legal', {
    templateUrl: 'views/legal-interpreting.html'
})
    .when('/medical', {
    templateUrl: 'views/medical-interpreting.html'
})
    .when('/newclient', {
    templateUrl: 'views/new-client.html'
})
    .when('/request', {
    templateUrl: 'views/request-interpreter.html'
})
    .when('/vri', {
    templateUrl: 'views/video-remote-interpreting.html'
});
});
```

links

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#!request">REQUEST AN INTERPRETER</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!newclient" class="arrow">HEARING/NEW INFO</a>
            <span>
            <a href="#!medical">MEDICAL INTERPRETING</a>
            <a href="#!legal">LEGAL INTERPRETING</a>
            <a href="#!business">BUSINESS INTERPRETING</a>
            <a href="#!educational">EDUCATIONAL INTERPRETING</a>
            <a href="#!vri">VRI</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#!consumers">DEAF CONSUMERS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!recruitment">INTERPRETER RECRUITMENT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!about">ABOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Modules

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<!-- Header section -->
<div ng-include="'views/header.html'"></div> <--- loads just fine, but froze.

<!-- Views section -->
<div ng-view></div>  <---------- it froze the webpage

<!-- Footer section -->
<div ng-include="'views/footer.html'"></div> <--- loads just fine, but froze.
```

Comment: any error in console ?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: open browser's console. hit F12 on keyboard

Comment: where is you module's code ?

Comment: Im showing `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token.` in app.js line 5

Comment: where have you defined your `myApp` module ?

Comment: and have you added `ng-route` dependency ?

Comment: I just add HTML and Modules...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169256/discussion-between-george-bailey-and-christian-luneborg).

Comment: So, its `ng-route` or `ng-view`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure`$locationProvider`like this :

```
app.config(function($locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: false,
    requireBase: true
  });
});
```

MyLink
Which give : http://blablabla.co:8888/blabla#/mylink/

Hope this help.

Comment: My link is just an example.... try the configuration of $locationProvider

Comment: I did and still blank page

Comment: Try to add '/#/' like  '/#!medical' before your href link and switch enabled to true in locationProvider config

Comment: `myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
 $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: true
  });` - this is what I did and still blank page after updating the link `/#!`